# Different font sizes while printing pure HTML in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, xslt, printing

I have two HTML documents that are generated in very similar ways: both are generated by XSL processing of XML. Their contents are a bit different but their basic structure is the same. There is no CSS in either of them. I try

```
right click on chrome window displaying the HTML -> print
```

as I want to print them. It turns out that the font sizes of the two documents visible in the chrome window are different. Font of one of them is significantly smaller than the first one. I have used common HTML tags, nothing fancy. And NO CSS. Why is this happening and how can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the default browser styling. If there is nothing defined than the brower will add its own defaults. This 'style' is diffrent with each client(browser). This also counts for printing

Comment: but then the styles should apply for both the documents right, if the browser is the same?

Comment: There is a diffrence between screen and print styles....its from the early days :P

Comment: Best thing you can do is just write a small style sheet with some basic definitions so it stays the same in both modus